# ggplot2 geom_area edges not vertical

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to fill slices (x-axis) of the area under a curve in different colors using ggplot's `geom_area`. But I somehow can't get the sides of the areas to be vertical. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
x = 1:10
pdat = data.frame(y = log(x), x = x)
ggplot(pdat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_area(aes(y = ifelse(y > 2 & y < 5, y, 0)), 
              fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that for x = 7 the y-value is now 0 but for x = 8 the y-value is 2.0794415 and so the area in between is interpolated.

You can instead use a subset of `pdat` for `geom_area`:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_area(data = pdat[pdat$y > 2 & pdat$y < 5,], aes(x = x, y = y), 
            fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = pdat, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that's it. Thanks!